# Def For Loop in Python with Return

Tags: python

I am trying to create this function in code with an additional option 9999:

```
y_train = ["yes", "no", "yes", "problem"]

y_train = np.where(y_train == "yes", 1, 0)
```

However, does not work for all entries

```
def encoder(x):
   for i in range(len(x)): 
        if i == "yes":
            return 1
        elif i == "no":
            return 0
        else:
            return 9999

y_train = encoder(y_train)
```

Comment: Did you mean: `for i in x:`?

Comment: Yes, but in returns only for one row.

Comment: You need y_train to be an array, not list or it won't broadcast in `np.where`: `y_train = np.array(["yes", "no", "yes", "problem"])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to adapt your code might be this:

```py
def encoder(x):
   ret = []
   for i in x: 
        if i == "yes":
            ret.append(1)
        elif i == "no":
            ret.append(0)
        else:
            ret.append(9999)
   return ret
```

Comment: I like your solution, however, for some reason, I got only 9999 for all entries.

Comment: Thank you :) this is what I was searching for ;)

Answer (score 1):

Adding another solution,

```
y_train = ["yes", "no", "yes", "problem"]

map_ = {"yes": 1, "no": 0, "problem": 9999}

print([map_[y] for y in y_train])
```

---

```
[1, 0, 1, 9999]
```

Comment: This won't work if there is a word other than 'problem'

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful as this is another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use pure numpy:

```
import numpy as np
y_train = np.array(["yes", "no", "yes", "problem"])
y_train = np.where(np.isin(y_train, ['yes', 'no']), y_train == 'yes', 9999)
```

output:

```
array([   1,    0,    1, 9999])
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of "here's what you need to do" without explanation, so I'll try to explain quickly

`return` in a function will cause the function to not only return that value, but terminates the function completely.

```py
def encoder(x):
   for i in range(len(x)): 
        if i == "yes":
            # This stops the function completely, the for loop is also stopped
            return 1
        elif i == "no":
            return 0
        else:
            return 9999

y_train = encoder(y_train)
```

I would recommend reading up on some more control flow. [This](https://realpython.com/python-return-statement/#recognizing-dead-code) might help. It explains things a lot better. For solutions, see someone else's answer. I recommend [quamrana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69104887/12370337), as it's more beginner friendly.

In addition, your if statements will never be fulfilled.

```py
def encoder(x):
   for i in range(len(x)): # i is a number
        if i == "yes": # i will never equal "yes", as it's a number. Did you mean x[i]?
            return 1
        elif i == "no": # i will also never be "no"
            return 0
        else:
            return 9999
```

Take a look at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/) for looping over arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and links :) I will have a look.